# Saving to assets in Expo project

Tags: javascript, expo, node.js-fs

So I'm getting into React Expo, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to save to the project folder I'm working in - or accessing one of my assets from the folder and writing to it.

For instance, if I have a 'someText.txt' file in my project structure, is there a way to write to that? Or alternatively, a way to generate a text file (or any other file) that gets included in the project folder?

From what I can see you'd usually use the expo-file-system (as found [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/)) for this, but my understanding is that it's not accessing the files of the project, but rather a different set of folders/files that are under the 'documentDirectory' umbrella? So not quite what I'm looking for.

I tried using Node's "fs" which have the features I'm looking for, it tells me that the React runtime doesn't include the Node standard library; and from what I've searched for, it seems like I need to run node as my backend with react as front-end, if I want to use the Node fs, which kinda defeats the purpose of using Expo

I *also* tried using React Native's "fs" module, but that's not compatable with Expo either